# Jquery Click function for conditional loading of Variation Fields not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working to hide and display fields based on the selection of one item from the radio group.
The parent element is "ul" with role radiogroup with options (buttons) in the form of "li". My goal is to show new fields if the user clicks on the specific button only.

The only thing in the element that I can target is attribute "aria-checked" which can be either true or false. It is working but the problem is that it works on 2nd click. It seems that the code picks the value of the attribute which was before the click instead of picking the value after the click.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    
     $("li").click(function() { 
    if ( $("[data-title='variation1']").attr('aria-checked') == 'false' ) {
    $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_subvariations']").css("display", "none");

    }   else if ( $("[data-title='variation1']").attr('aria-checked') == 'true' ) {
    $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_subvariations']").css("display", "flex");
} 

    
  });
```

I know I'm missing something which can be done but unfortunately, I'm not getting it right. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Show us HTML and make [mre] using snippet by pressing <> button in editor, so we can see it for our selfs...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for informing me about this. Actually, it does not work like a normal HTML radio button that's why it was not possible to reproduce functioning buttons here without including external JS. It is closer to this (https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20170628/examples/radio/radio-1/radio-1.html)  the only difference is the use of <ul> and <li> instead of <div>.  Now it's working fine for me after wrapping it inside "setTimeout" function with 100 ms. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the above code inside setTimeout function so that it gets the value of the attribute after 100 milliseconds of the click on the button. Now it checks updated value after a click.
Here is the final code that worked for me:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    
     $("li").click(function() { 
      setTimeout(function() {
    if ( $("[data-title='variation1']").attr('aria-checked') == 'false' ) {
    $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_subvariations']").css("display", "none");

    }   else if ( $("[data-title='variation1']").attr('aria-checked') == 'true' ) {
    $("[data-attribute_name='attribute_pa_subvariations']").css("display", "flex");
} 

  }, 100);  
  });
});
```